# Why the PHP code in the index.php execute multiple times? (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess

When you open "Home Page" on my website (index.php), PHP code stores information about your IP address in a database MySQL. Unfortunately, he does it several times in a row. Most likely the problem is with the .htaccess file. When I emptied its contents, everything was back to normal, but I have some rules there that I would like to have. Where did I go wrong?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Hide .PHP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

# Cache for img and fonts 1 year
<FilesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|woff2)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000"
</FilesMatch>

# Cache for js and css 30 days
<FilesMatch ".(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

# Redirect 404 to homepage
ErrorDocument 404 https://xyz.pl/

# Hide Apache version in signature
ServerSignature Off
```